# Prove $y = z$ if $y^p = z^p$ where $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y, z \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$

Tags: real-analysis

As above. I am beginner in analysis. I don't know how rigorously you have to prove things. To me it's obvious.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\Bbb R_{++}$?  Does $\Bbb R_{++} = \{ w \in \Bbb R, \; w > 0\}$?  That's what I'll assume until further notice.  Cheers!

Comment: y > 0 and z > 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y^p=z^p\implies (y-z)(y^{p-1}+y^{p-2}z+y^{p-3}z^2+\cdots +z^{p-1})=0$$
But since both $y,z$ are positive,

$$y^{p-1}+y^{p-2}z+y^{p-3}z^2+\cdots +z^{p-1}>0$$
So $y-z=0\implies y=z$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=x^p$ and $p\in\mathbb N^*$ then $f'(x)=px^{p-1}>0$ for $x>0$.

So $f \nearrow$ strictly on $(0,+\infty)$, which implies injectivity.

Thus $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see, using elementary algebra, that for

$p \in \Bbb N, \tag 0$

we have

$y^p - z^p = (y - z)(y^{p - 1} + y^{p - 2}z + y^{p - 3}z^2 + \ldots + yz^{p - 2} + z^{p - 1})$
$= (y - z)\displaystyle \sum_1^p y^{p - k}z^{k - 1}; \tag 1$

since

$y, z > 0, \tag 2$

we also have

$y^{p - 1} + y^{p - 2}z + y^{p - 3}z^2 + \ldots + yz^{p - 2} + z^{p - 1}$
$= \displaystyle \sum_1^p y^{p - k}z^{k - 1} > 0; \tag 3$

note that every term in these sums is positive.

Then if

$y^p = z^p, \tag 4$

$y^p - z^p = 0, \tag 5$

and so

$(y - z)(y^{p - 1} + y^{p - 2}z + y^{p - 3}z^2 + \ldots + yz^{p - 2} + z^{p - 1})$
$= (y - z)\displaystyle \sum_1^p y^{p - k}z^{k - 1} = 0, \tag 6$

and in light of (3) this forces

$y - z = 0 \Longrightarrow y = z. \tag 7$

$OE\Delta$.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about logarithms and exponentials, you could also observe that $x^p = y^p$ implies $\ln(x^p)= \ln(y^p)$, that is, $p\ln(x) = p\ln(y)$. It follows that $\ln(x) = \ln(y)$, whence $e^{\ln(x)} = e^{\ln(y)}$, that is, $x = y$.

Comment: This excercise almost certainly predates logs and exponents and is the first step to verify that such concepts are well defined..

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with induction and/or the well ordering principal?

If we assume $y \ne z$ and wolog we assume $0 < y < z$ then $y^1 < z^1$.  Let's assume there is a $y^k \ge z^k$.  By well ordering principal there most be so *first* $k$ where that is true.

But that would mean $y^{k-1} < z^{k-1}$.  Byt then $y^k = y^{k-1}*y < z^{k-1}*y < z^{k-1}*z = z^k$ and thus we have a contradiction.

Alternatively by induction as $y^1 < z^1$ and $y^{k-1} < z^{k-1}\implies $y^k < z^k$ we can never have anything *but* $y^p < z^p$.

So if $y^p = z^p$ we can't have $y < z$ and by wolog (or symmetry) we can't have $y > z$ either.  So if $y^p = z^p$ having $y = z$ is our only option.

....

or.  Consider $y^p = z^p$ so $y^p - z^p = 0$ and notice (although this requires induction to actually state) that $(y-z)(y^{p-1} + y^{p-2}z + y^{p-3}z^2 + .... + y^2z^{p-3} + yz^{p-2}+z^{p-1}) = y^p - z^p=0$.

Now all $y^iz^k > 0$ so $(y^{p-1} + y^{p-2}z + y^{p-3}z^2 + .... + y^2z^{p-3} + yz^{p-2}+z^{p-1}) \ne 0$.  So $(y-z)(y^{p-1} + y^{p-2}z + y^{p-3}z^2 + .... + y^2z^{p-3} + yz^{p-2}+z^{p-1}) = 0 \iff (y-z) = 0$.  So $y-z = 0$ and $y= z$>

If $0 < y < z$ then $y^1 < z^1$ so we can't have $x^p =z^p$ if $p=1$.

Now if for some $p=k$ that $y^k < z^k$ then $y^{k+1} = y^k*y < z^k*y$ and $z^k *y < z^k*z = z^{k+1}$.  So by induction it is true that $y^p < z^p$ for all $p$ and so if $y^p = z^p$ it